# 2013 BCS in Designer: data source objects do not exist

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, bdc, external-data-column

We've inherited an SP2013 solution, which had previously been upgraded from SP2007.

The BDC service was converted as well, and appears to be working in most respects - external lists, external content types and external columns all behave largely as expected.

However, one pre-existing ECT is causing some headaches. The data sources the operations are pointing at **appear to not exist**, being TableX and TableY in a SQL database... yet nothing by these names exists in the database itself. Trying to edit any of these operations in Designer brings up the error **"This operation cannot be matched with any objects in your data source. There may be an error in the operation definition in the Business Data Connectivity Metadata Store or the stat source schema has changed since the operation was created"**.

Any lists that have external columns based on this ECT work as expected, allowing a user to add new data, refresh existing data etc, which shows that **the data source does exist and is reachable**. Changes made directly in the database are reflected in the list once a refresh is performed.

We've checked permissions on the list and database, tried recreating all permissions on the metadata store, the BDC and the relevant ECT objects, as well as restarting all relevant services and IIS. We think at this point that the operation/ECT itself is corrupt. Unfortunately since this is an inherited system, there is little to no documentation about the upgrade, or the setup of the initial ECT & operations.

The question is, under what circumstances is this possible? That a 'non-existent' data source can be in use but the refresh still works - has anyone encountered this before?